# link_to_add and link_to_remove - clicking on them dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nested-forms

I am using a gem https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form and I have a model which has `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. While it works nice, sometimes I want to be able add / remove (mostly add) a form on a page which is always added / removed by a button:

```
.row
  #tasks
    = f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form|
      ..............

      = task_form.link_to_remove "Remove", class: "btn btn-danger"
      = f.link_to_add  "Add task", :tasks, class: "btn btn-default", data: { target: "#tasks" }
```

In other words, I want to click on `link_to_add` and `link_to_remove` dynamically (not by mouse), probably by calling a method on it which should exist in `nested_form` gem. Of course, I can that by javascript by **triggering click event** for the button but my gut tells me there must be a simpler, more natural way to do so. Is there any?

**update**:

I'm ok with javascript, of course. I'm not really ok with **triggering** click event for the button as there must be a simpler and standard way in `nested_form`.

Comment: not really. Basically if you do not want to refresh page to do this all you have in browser is JavaScript.

Comment: BTW you may be better using the [`cocoon` gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) - which I believe does a very similar job to `nested_form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure on what you are trying to accomplish here. On one side you say you want to do it dynamically, but at the same time, you don't want to use JavaScript. Sounds conflicting to me.

Any way, if you this in your `new` method:

```
def new
  @to_do = ToDo.new
  @to_do.tasks.build
end
```

Then in your `form` you will have one set of task fields show up on page load without having to click on `add` button.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, or something else.

PS: I don't see what is un-natural about JavaScript. This gem that you are using is totally dependent on JavaScript.

**Update**

Now that you've updated your question. I would suggest reading the source code of the gem and figure out which function is bound to the button click event. Then you can bind the same function to any of your events that you like.

Having said that, Let's take a look at this file:

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_nested_form.js

Check out the bottom few lines. Add button click event is bound to `nestedFormEvents.addFields` function. Go ahead and bind your events to this function and you won't have to trigger the button click.

Comment: Clicking on "Add new tasks" button adds a new form on a **page**, right? Say I want it  to be added by another event as well. How?

Comment: Any thing like that will have to use JavaScript. But your requirement that you don't want to use JavaScript is what is confusing. You can easily simulate a button click (without having to click the mouse) using jquery like this: `$('#button-id').click();`. Put this in a function and bind that function to any event that you like.

Comment: I didn't say I don't want to use javascript.

Comment: That's what I said: I could trigger click event but ...? I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at it. But "what" do I have to call "addFields" function **on**?

Comment: I mean, should I call `window.NestedFormEvents.addFields()` to add a new form on a page? It says "undefined is not a function".

Comment: created a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**DOM**

The `javascript` element of this solution, as mentioned by `San` is always going to be there (already is); so the question of whether this is done in JS or not *should* be "how do I do this?"

Frankly, I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do exactly - so apologies if this answer seems a little broad :)

[image: -]

The bottom line is your answer is entirely dependent on the [`DOM` (document object model)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) - this is *basically* your loaded HTML page which your browser will then "digest"

Javascript famously works by sitting on top of the `DOM`, allowing you to interact with the various elements on the page, by *binding* events to those elements.

Every time you change something dynamically on your page ("without refreshing") is done through Javascript's manipulation of the DOM. This means if you wish to manipulate your DOM without reloading the page, you're going to *have* to use Javascript somewhere along the path

---

**Suggestions**

You mention you want to "click the links `dynamically`" - what do you mean exactly?

If you want to load / remove elements from your form, you'll either need to use Ajax to load the form elements from the controller, *or* replicate the elements with different ID's (I think `nested_forms` does this anyway)

It would help big time if you provide details on the use case you're looking to implement. From what I can see - I guess you're looking to add files if certain parameters are met (such as a checkbox is clicked)?